# Concatenate multiple 7zip archives without having to decompress/recompress them

Tags: 7-zip

I'm working on a deployment system of some necessary dependencies* to my program. I create 7z archives stored on my server for each dependency. The client checks if the archive available on the server is newer than the most recent time they updated their local copy, and if so copies it to their local system overwriting any previous version of the dependency.

This works out pretty well, but I have a problem. For the initial installation, users download a primary executable, and that primary executable then goes and downloads all the necessary dependencies. This leads to a pain point as the user has to wait for the primary executable to download the dependencies on the first run -- Not a great first introduction to my app.

Currently, my app installs via a 7z self extracting archive. I would like to include the external dependencies in this archive, but have run into a problem building that archive -- compressing all of the necessary dependencies into one module takes a long time, so builds aren't terribly quick.

All of this leads to my question -- Is it possible to concatenate several 7z archives into a single archive without decompressing/recompressing them?

<sub>*These are dependencies that for various reasons I cannot directly compile into my application. I am allowed to distribute them, but they must remain seperate entities from my app.</sub>

Comment: Why not just store the other archives?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams If I understand you, that's basically what I'm doing. The archives containing dependencies are more or less static on the server, I might update one once every three months -- It's just that if possible, I'd like to concatenate the stored archived dependencies into the primary setup sfx file to allow initial downloads to contain all necessary dependencies.

Comment: Is it a problem to store the files outside of an archive on your own harddisk? If not, then you can simply open the 7z archive with the 7zip gui app, and drag all the files in, so they are added to the archive.

Comment: Are you saying that you create the SFX first, and then add the other archives to it after the fact?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams Not quite. Dependencies sit on my server more or less static -- But my app updates pretty regularly. When building my app, every time I build it, I have a script to create that SFX file. In part of creating that SFX file, I archive both my app and all of my dependencies, and use that archive for the SFX. It's the fact that archiving all the dependencies takes so long that is the pain point here.

Comment: Do you tell the build to use 0% compression for the dependencies?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams Not explicitely, I'm just using the 7z command line with default options.

Comment: Well then do it explicitly. Otherwise you're compressing, not storing.